# iPhone freeze when using QuickActionItems

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, 3dtouch, quickaction

I have added 3D Touch on my app icon to show Quick Action menu. I think I should have it all set up correctly.

The problem is that when I am choosing one of the items in the Quick Action menu, the iPhone freezes for a few seconds before it opens up the application.

This is my `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import Parse


@available(iOS 9.0, *)
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        Parse.setApplicationId("xx",
            clientKey: "xx")

        let currentInstallation: PFInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        currentInstallation.badge = 0
        currentInstallation.saveEventually()

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {

        let rootNavigationViewController = window!.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
        let rootViewController = rootNavigationViewController?.viewControllers.first as UIViewController?

        rootNavigationViewController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)

        if shortcutItem.type == "JEGHARALDRI" {
            rootViewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("JEGHARALDRISEGUE", sender: nil)
        }
        if shortcutItem.type == "PLING" {
            rootViewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("PLINGSEGUE", sender: nil)
        }
        if shortcutItem.type == "FLASKETUTENPEKERPÅ" {
            rootViewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("FLASKETUTENPEKERPÅSEGUE", sender: nil)
        }
        if shortcutItem.type == "KORTETTALER" {
            rootViewController?.performSegueWithIdentifier("KORTETTALERSEGUE", sender: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you handle it? Looks like it crashing because the app don't know what to display

Comment: @QuentinRibierre Well it does not crash. I shows what i what it to do, but the problem is that the iPhone freeze for a few seconds before it opens up the application.

Answer (score 1):

I think your app delegate should more looks like something like this

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    //MARK: - Properties

    var window: UIWindow?

    lazy var quickActionManager: QuickActionsManager = {
        return QuickActionsManager()
    }()

    //MARK: - AppDelegate Methods

    func application(application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
    {
        return self.setupQuickActions(launchOptions)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem
        shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void)
    {
        completionHandler(self.quickActionManager.handleShortcut(shortcutItem))
    }

    //MARK: - Private Methods

    private func setupQuickActions(launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
    {
        guard let shortcutItem = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey]
        as? UIApplicationShortcutItem else { return false }
        return self.quickActionManager.handleShortcut(shortcutItem)
    }
}
```

And so then you get all the logic to handle a quick action in your quick action manager, which would looks something like this

```
//MARK: - Public Methods

    func handleShortcut(shortcut: UIApplicationShortcutItem?) -> Bool
    {
        guard let shortcut = shortcut else { return false }
        // Get the key of the shortcutItem
        let key = self.shortKeyForType(shortcut.type)
        // Check if that key is the key of a knowed viewController
        guard let viewControllerKey = ViewControllerKeys(rawValue: key) else { return false }
        // Try to show This View Controller
        return self.showViewController(viewControllerKey)
    }
```

Assuming you got an enum of viewController to display matching each quick actions.

I hope this answer your question, let me know if you got some more.

Comment: Thanks! But the last code gives me two errors: http://s11.postimg.org/sqn14qpsj/Screen_Shot_2016_01_08_at_16_11_57.png